# Transfer ownership of question

Tags: feature-request, questions

I have a question at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/826541/portrait-primary-display-rotates-touchpad/902873#902873) which was not answered effectively for a period of time. Since then I don't have the subject hardware anymore, so I cannot test the upcoming ideas. I would gladly transfer the ownership of this question to anyone who is interested in it.

Is there any way doing it?

Would it be a good idea to have an "offer ownership" feature? The target of the offer could be

- The ones who starred this question. It may involve selecting a winner.
- A specific user.
- Anyone who cares to take it. First responder wins.

Comment: Make it a wiki if you really want

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to transfer ownership.